# Powershell file and directory names as strings, sans decorations

Tags: string, powershell, filenames

Frequently I want to do something like:

```
 $foo=ls foo.txt|select FullName
 $bar=$foo.split("\\");  #  or replace or some such
```

But if I now look at the strings in bar they look like this:

```
 @{FullName=C:\path\to\foo.txt}
```

Since I know how long the decorations are I can manually get the substring.  But that seems hacky - is there a way to just get the path part as a string?

Edit: to illustrate another similar issue, based on some questions, if I do:

```
 $foo -replace("\\","/")
```

I get:

```
 @{FullName=C:/src/tss/THSS-Deployment-Config/foo.txt}
```

I am doing lots of manipulations of these file names for a migration between different CM repositories.  I was thinking 'if I could just get the whole path as a string'...

This is my first serious outing into PS.  So maybe my mindset is just wrong.

Comment: You are treating an object as a string which will not work in your case. That is the point of `select -ExpandProperty FullName` and `(gci foo.txt).fullname`. What you are trying to manipulate is an object with a fullname property which why you see the hashtable notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few quick ways, all using the `Split-Path` cmdlet which is perfect for this:

```powershell
$foo= ls foo.txt | select FullName
$bar = Split-Path $foo.fullname
```

Or:

```powershell
$foo= ls foo.txt | select -ExpandProperty FullName
$bar = Split-Path $foo
```

Or even shorter:

```powershell
$bar = Split-Path (gci foo.txt).fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

@arco444 gave me the missing piece.  To get the full path with the filename as a string, the easiest thing I could come up with was:

```
 $bar=(Split-Path $foo.FullName) +"\"+ (Split-Path $foo -leaf)
```

I'm not sure if there's an easier way to combine get the whole path as a string.

Comment: Like this: `$bar = (gci foo.txt).fullname`. I thought you only wanted the directory portion.

Comment: I will assume this is an example and not your real code however i am not understanding the purpose of you example since you are just outputting the Fullname again. If you needed to break them up you could just use the `directoryName` and `Name`. This would do the same thing `$bar = "{0}\{1}" -f $foo.DirectoryName,$foo.Name`

Comment: @Matt If you do any manipulation to the string as a FullName object, you get the {FullName=... decorations.  There is lots of stuff I am doing with these filenames, it is just easier if they are plain strings when  I am doing it.  I'll add another example that makes it more clear.